# how to remove all li in my ul through with it id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a ul list.

I want to remove all li in my ul through with it id?

Answer (score 19):

All that jQuery stuff. :-)

A plain old javascript version:

```
  var ul = document.getElementById('<ul id>');
  if (ul) {
    while (ul.firstChild) {
      ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild));
    }
  }
```

You could also set:

```
  ul.innerHTML = '';
```

or even:

```
  ul.parentNode.replaceChild(ul.cloneNode(false), ul);
```

but I prefer the first method.

Comment: @ThiefMaster it's great and does all things.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum but does it do math?!

Answer (score 13):

If you want to remove all `li` elements inside a `ul` with a certain ID:

```
$('#id-of-ul > li').remove();
```

Since `ul` has only `li` children anyway you can also use `$('#id-of-ul').empty()` to delete all its children.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `empty()` :

```
$('#listId').empty();
```

Answer (score 3):

*Using jQuery

Did you mean that you want to remove all li with the same id? (This is how I interpreted the question)

```
$('#id').remove()
```

**(Remember that using the same ID on multiple DOM elements is not considered good programming and should always be avoided! Always use a good IDE to chceck your code)**

You can also remove using the class (this is a better way to remove grouped elements by class name)

```
$('.className').remove()
```

Those two functions will remove ALL elements with the ID / Class 
To restrict removing id's / class'es from LI only

```
$('li #id').remove();
$('li .className').remove();
```

You can also make a function in JavaScript. This will remove any DOM with a class itemDelete clicked on it.

```
$('.itemDelete').live("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().get(0).id;
        $("#" + id).remove();
    });
```

Make a loop and call a function?

```
function deleteLI(id) {
            $("#" + id).remove();
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all li with the same id"? The id attribute **must** be unique.

Comment: Yea it SHOULD BE but- i have seen bad programming with THE SAME ID's before..... I interpreted his question like that. But i should have pointed out it is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

The quick dirty, pure js way of doing this would be:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("ul_id");
ul.innerHTML = "";
```

This of course assumes there are not other non-li children that you don't want to clobber.

Comment: A UL can **only** have LI child nodes.

Comment: @RobG - sure, in theory yes. I've seen otherwise though, and I didn't want to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a call to the [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

```
// Removes a single element with the specified id
$('#id-of-the-element').remove();
```

Have a look at the documentation for some more information.

Comment: The second example is incorrect - see my comment to @Sumit's answer and/or http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/2hDgD/

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Indeed, why doesn't it?

Comment: Because `$('selector1').remove('selector2')` just filters the results from `selector1` using `selector2`. It does not filter its children.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:
`$('#uiId').remove('li');`

Comment: This removes `li#uiId`. The selector passed to `remove()` does not select children but filters the initial set. And a jQuery object with a `#id` selector is supposed to contain not more than one element anyway. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/2hDgD/